# How to find battery usage of an application over time?

Tags: android, windows-phone

Currently I'm working on a study where I need to take accurate battery usage information of a particular application over some period of time. Is there any way of getting this information on Android and/or Windows Phone?

Comment: How do you define the amount of battery an application is using? What if I turn my phone's GPS or WiFi on while using your application? How does the battery consumed by the screen at different brightnesses affect your application's consumption? What about other running services? In the end, this is a metric that you will not be able to reliably track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you will be able to get to get "accurate battery usage information of a particular application over some period of time" will be to invest in a Qualcomm MDP device and use Trepn. The MDP series have special hardware instrumentation for detailed power measurement; the Trepn software package allows you to collect the results.

Answer (score 1):

On android if you go to battery in system settings, you can see how much battery an application or service has used.

Comment: Not really. That screen is largely guesswork, per Dianne Hackborn's quote as seen in Mr. Chetnir's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. The short answer is that the SDK doesn't give you such information, so you will have to estimate it based on the behavior of the applications that you are monitoring.

Diane Hackborn, an Android framework engineer, already addressed this question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/NExT6OF0dyQ).

> No [*there is no API for looking for the battery usage details per application*].  The way this is done is very complicated, using an ever-evolving
>   set of measurements of various operations applications are doing and
>   computing them against a device-specific power profile to construct
>   the UI.  This is only intended to provide rough estimates as shown in
>   the UI, this is not a facility for applications to use.